# OFAC declaration for travelling to Cuba from US

Tags: usa, transit, tourist-visas, connecting-flights, cuba

I will be travelling from New-York to Cuba as my flight back to Europe is from Havana. I will buy the tourist card from the US airlines I am traveling with but I need to select one option in OFAC form out of 12 options. What should I select? I will be in Havana for tourism for three days before as it seems tourism or transiting is not an option.

Comment: What is your nationality? Are you travelling independently or as part of an organised group?

Comment: Indian national travelling solo with EU residence

Comment: For the record, these rules have always applied to everyone flying from the US to Cuba - they are not a recent change and those who say that the rules only apply to US citizens or residents are wrong. The June 2019 changes just tweaked the categories.

Answer (score 8):

Note: It appears that recent US rule changes have made these OFAC declarations applicable to anyone transiting through a US airport whether they are a US citizen/resident or not. Thus it appears that the US won't permit anyone to travel from the US to Cuba for tourism. The original answer was:

---

For those of you playing along at home, [here is a copy of the Cuba travel declaration](https://www.copaair.com/documents/1508201/1510489/declaracion-jurada-de-viajes-a-cuba-en.pdf/6a14894f-6c33-4e27-b47a-41ccad16b511).

You don't select one of the 12 options for US citizens/residents.

You should instead select: **I am not a citizen or resident of the United States.**

Comment: As simple as that? just declare you are not US citizen at immigration and fly?. thanks for the info

Comment: @Kumar The US - Cuba travel sanctions apply only to US citizens/residents. They're not applicable to anyone else.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the answer to this later question [Travel from the US to Cancun with a layover in Cuba as an European citizen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/132198/travel-from-the-us-to-cancun-with-a-layover-in-cuba-as-an-european-citizen) Cuba travel restrictions apply not only to citizens and residents but to anyone within the US.

The change took effect from June 5, 2019. https://www.united.com/web/en-US/content/travel/destination/international/cuba.aspx