# Does a visit to Cuba affect my ability to travel to the US under the VWP?

Tags: us-visa-waiver-program, cuba

I understand there are restrictions for visiting Cuba for US citizens and residents.

However, as a non-US citizen or resident, if I go on holiday in Cuba, then attempt to visit the US a few weeks or months later, will I encounter difficulties getting my VWP clearance or should I expect extensive questioning on arrival in the US?

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/120223/ofac-declaration-for-travelling-to-cuba-from-us